# Debugging CoffeeScript line-by-line

Tags: debugging, coffeescript

Is there a way to debug CoffeeScript line-by-line?

I understand that it compiles into Javascript. But this sounds like it could make it a pain to debug.

Comment: Since the generated JavaScript preserves indentation, names of  functions and variables debugging it's not nearly as bad as most people think. Also, support for "Source Maps" is coming (in the next version?) in CoffeeScript to address this:  http://www.coffeescriptlove.com/2012/04/source-maps-for-coffeescript.html

Comment: You can configure [coffeescript debbuging in JetBrains WebStorm](http://www.youtube.com/watch?feature=player_detailpage&v=Sl1Uk3zT5Fg)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

At the moment it is quite a pain to debug CoffeeScript.  Most people use lots of unit tests.

There is some work being done on debugging for CoffeeScript but it is probably a while away before we'll have a really good debugger.  One example is http://www.infoq.com/news/2011/08/debug-languages-on-javascript-vm

Comment: Creepy unit tests to avoid happy call-stack debugging?? Yikes!

Comment: I'll drop bugger here: https://github.com/jkrems/bugger. It has step-by-step debugging for coffee-script 2.x.

For coffee-script 1.x there's the strongloop-fork of node-inspector: https://github.com/strongloop/node-inspector

Answer (score 36):

**Update**: there's currently a [redesign](https://github.com/michaelficarra/CoffeeScriptRedux) of coffeescript compiler that generates [source maps](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/developertools/sourcemaps/), which should enable you to debug your coffeescript in most recent versions of Google Chrome (18 and upwards I think).

I think it's not production-ready yet, but it's worth mentioning.

Comment: Pay attention that source maps are available only for Chrome Canary, WebKit nightly and Firefox 23+. BTW, that's will be the best way to debug compiled javascript code at client-side, so +1 for ur answer ;)

Comment: Available in Chromium 39, current version in Ubuntu Trusty repositories. And, well, "non-production-readiness" doesn't restrict its usage during development.

Answer (score 29):

if you are running coffeescript from the terminal you can debug it line-for-line using [node-inspector](https://github.com/dannycoates/node-inspector/), launching your script this way:

```
coffee --nodejs --debug-brk yourscript.coffee
```

Comment: for debugger auto connection I'm using `coffee --nodejs debug yourscript.coffee`

Answer (score 9):

Yes, with [node-inspector](http://strongloop.com/strongblog/debug-coffeescript-node-js-inspector/):

```
npm install -g node-inspector
```

By putting the statement `debugger` into the source code of your script, you will enable a breakpoint. Then type in a console:

```
coffee -c -m myscript.coffee
node-debug myscript.js
```

Node Inspector supports source-maps out of the box, so no extra configuration is needed.

For more information [see this post](http://strongloop.com/strongblog/debug-coffeescript-node-js-inspector/).

Comment: It's fascinating but how do I make him take my `require 'something.coffee'` into account?

Answer (score 5):

Coffeescript now supports source maps:
http://coffeescript.org/

Jetbrains for example supports this feature: https://blog.jetbrains.com/ruby/2013/01/whats-mining-coffeescript-debugger/

Comment: There is Jetbrains: http://blog.jetbrains.com/ruby/2013/01/whats-mining-coffeescript-debugger/

Answer (score 1):

now is 2020, i find this question, and then i find vscode support sourcemap, so we can use vscode to debug coffee directly.

btw, i think coffee need a great improve. just like static data.
anyway here is my launch.json:

```json
{
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [{
        "type": "node",
        "request": "launch",
        "name": "Launch Program",
        "skipFiles": [
            "<node_internals>/**"
        ],
        "program": "${file}", //important, make sure debug current file
        "outFiles": [
            "${workspaceFolder}/dist/api/api.js" //important, where to find sourcemap js file
        ]
    }]
}
```