# Node.js with CoffeeScript, how to debug?

Tags: javascript, node.js, coffeescript

I am used to being a Front-End Developer. I am new to NodeJS.

I always use CoffeeScript to build Front-end code.

I have a coffeescript file like the following:

```
http = require 'http'

http.createServer (req, res) ->
  res.writeHead 200, {'Content-Type': 'text/plain'}
  res.end 'Hello World\n'
.listen 1337

console.log 'Server running at http://127.0.0.1:1337/'
```

So I type command `$ coffee server.coffee`, It works fine, the same effect with `$ node server.js`

So I decided I write my NodeJS application using CoffeScript, When I deploy it to the production environment I will compile all CoffeeScript files to Javascript files.

So:

1. I don't know how to debug CoffeeScript.
2. I am studying NodeJS by myself, I don't know if the above steps are correct or reasonable

Comment: 1. Source maps, 2. Looks good.

Comment: Possibly duplicated http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11068023/debugging-coffeescript-line-by-line

Comment: I would say it depends. What exactly do you want to debug? The compiled script itself? Or an operation it does?

Comment: @ChiChou , Thanks for you reply, I have more issue in my question, It's not duplicated.

Comment: Use [source maps](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/tools-and-tips/source-maps-101/) and [tag:node] built-in [debugger](http://nodejs.org/api/debugger.html).

Comment: Somehow related: I believe there is no need to compile coffeescript in production. See http://stackoverflow.com/a/7596458/738944 for more details on this issue.

Answer (score 0):

This took me forever to figure out.

```
coffee --nodejs debug server.coffee
```

Apparently you can pass options to node by specifying the --nodejs flag. More on that in [this other post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13548196/how-to-enable-harmony-in-coffeescript)